# Ruby On Rails Tutorial - Gravatar Injects Text and Not Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Q: How can I fix this problem without hacking the tutorial code too much? I would like to reduce moving away from the tutorial code.**

I am working through the online Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. In Chapter 7 we begin to bring in profile photos using the a Gravatar plugin. (This does not appear compatible with Rails 3 - but this is not the question.)

I have got the plugin working however my Rails App does not show the Gravatar image. It shows a text string. ie It injects the Gravatar code as text rather than an html tag.

Instead of showing the following in the file:

```
<img class="gravatar" alt="" width="52" height="52" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b58996c504c5638798eb6b511e6f49af?rating=PG&amp;size=52" />
```

It shows this (displaying the text, rather than image):

```
&lt;img class=&quot;gravatar&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;52&quot; height=&quot;52&quot; src=&quot;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b58996c504c5638798eb6b511e6f49af?rating=PG&amp;amp;size=52&quot; /&gt;
```

My view file contains:

```
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
```

The Gravatar plugin contains (gravatar.rb):

```
def gravatar(email, options={})
  src = h(gravatar_url(email, options))
  options = DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(options)
  [:class, :alt, :size].each { |opt| options[opt] = h(options[opt]) }
  "<img class=\"#{options[:class]}\" alt=\"#{options[:alt]}\" width=\"#{options[:size]}\" height=\"#{options[:size]}\" src=\"#{src}\" />"
end
```

Other info:

I am working on a Windows 7 box running Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell Rails that the HTML is trusted (and so shouldn't be escaped) by using the [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) method:

```
def gravatar_for email, options={}
  # ...
  "<img class=\"#{options[:class]}\" ... />".html_safe
end
```

Background: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Incidentally you can, and probably should, sidestep this issue neatly and entirely by just using Rails' built-in [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper, which has the bonus effect of getting rid of that long, ugly hard-coded string:

```
def gravatar_for email, options={}
  options = DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge options
  options[:size] = "%{size}x%{size}" % options  # image_tag expects e.g. "48x48"

  image_tag gravatar_url(email, options), options
end
```

(Don't let that `"..." % options` throw you off—it's basically [shorthand for](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<%= raw gravatar_for(user, size: 52) %>
```

The default behavior since rails 3 is to escape HTML when using `<%= ... %>` ; `raw` disable this behavior.

[More details](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)